# No module named 'PyQt3D'

Tags: pyqt5

I have installed PyQt3D in the same virtual environment where I have PyQt5 up and running properly. However, I cannot import PyQt3D

```
>>> import PyQt3D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt3D'
```

The module is properly installed

```
$ pip list
PyQt3D (5.9.2)
PyQt5 (5.9.1)
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please look at the examples they ship. There is no module names PyQt3D, as this is not how their modules (or Qt-Modules at all) are named.

Comment: As far as I know [this is the only page](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt3d/intro) about PyQt3D and there is zero examples there, nor through google search

Comment: The examples **they ship** are in their source distribution. If you download PyQt3D (although not if you just install it from the PyPI) there is a folder `examples`.

Comment: Ah allright, this is perfect. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by searching through my python packages using `pydoc`.

PyQt3D does not expose an importable module name, but rather it adds the following submodules to the PyQt5 package, which is consistent with Qt5 documentation:

```
Qt3DCore
Qt3DExtras
Qt3DInput
Qt3DLogic
Qt3DRender
```

Objects defined by these submodules can then be imported normally like this

```
from PyQt5.Qt3DCore import QEntity
```